# How to make an <li> number identical to existing h2 tag

Tags: css

I'm using a WordPress theme where the CSS for `<li>` elements is substantially different from the `<h2>` tags I want to use for a numbered list.

I tried nesting the numbered list like `<h2><ol><li>Item one</li></ol></h2>` but the theme just strips out the nesting making them separate from each other.

I'm really weak on CSS and styling, but I'm assuming there must be a way to cause my `<li>` marker tags to inherit their styling from another style?

Is there a way to say something like `<li marker> = <h2>` whereby it copies the style identically?  I'd rather not have to look up and add each marker style element manually in case I ever change themes?

I'll initially need to do this inline, as I don't want to change my style sheet for fear of messing up many other pages that might be using the `<li>` tag.

Thank you.

Comment: That is invalid HTML. A `<h2>` element may not contain a list element.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any way to do this in raw CSS without a preprocessor like SASS. Only option I can think of is for all the styles you care about, like color, inline `color: inherit` to override li values and inherit the parent values from h2. For example:

**Theme CSS**

```
li {
    color: red;
}
h2 {
    color: purple;
}
```

**HTML** *(Inline style inherit to use h2 color instead of li color)*

```
<h2><ol>
    <li style="color:inherit">Hello</li>
</ol></h2>
```

**Result:**

"Hello" is purple because the `inherit` tells the HTML to use the parent style (h2) instead of the style from the stylesheet (li). This only works because an inline style has higher precedence than anything from the CSS file.

**JS Fiddle example:** https://jsfiddle.net/Chris_Hayes/ocmkge8n/

Comment: Chris thank you.  Unfortunately, the WP theme just strips away the (h2) style from the source so there's no parent/child relationship.  I may just have to manually override the style in the pages that need it.  Thank you.

Comment: That would be invalid HTML. Anything output by a CSS pre-processor would still be CSS so anything a pre-processor can do CSS can do.

Comment: @Rob I was referring to using something like `extend` or a `mixin` in SASS. HTML/CSS to my knowledge doesn't have anything of the like. SASS would still be copying CSS around, but OP wouldn't have to manually copy styles.